# Sort Array in Array

Tags: arrays, sorting, array-merge, array-unique

I have following array result:

Example:

```
[
    {
         id: "1",
         league: {
              name: "World Club Friendlies",
              team: "Simple 1 & Simple 2"
          }
    },
    {
         id: "2",
         league: {
              name: "Senegal Ligue 2",
              team: "Simple"
          }
    },
    {
         id: "3",
         league: {
              name: "World Club Friendlies",
              team: "Simple 3 & Simple 4"
          }
    },
]
```

The **First** and **Third** **league names** are **similar**.

The above code output looks like this:

> League Name: **World Club Friendlies** / Team: Simple 1 & Simple 2
>
> League Name: Senegal Ligue 2 / Team: Simple
>
> League Name: **World Club Friendlies** / Team: Simple 3 & Simple 4

Now i need to print following result:

> League Name: **World Club Friendlies** / Team: *Simple 1 & Simple 2 & Simple 3 & Simple 4*
>
> League Name: Senegal Ligue 2 / Team: Simple

I have somthing like this code:

```
foreach($content as $result){
   echo $result['league']['name'];
   echo $result['team'];
}
```

Comment: No any Body ? ............

Answer (score 0):

Use `reduce` and check for `team name` as key and apply the condition that you want as follows:

```js
var data = [{
    id: "1",
    league: {
      name: "World Club Friendlies",
      team: "Simple 1 & Simple 2"
    }
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    league: {
      name: "Senegal Ligue 2",
      team: "Simple"
    }
  },
  {
    id: "3",
    league: {
      name: "World Club Friendlies",
      team: "Simple 3 & Simple 4"
    }
  },
]

var res = data.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  if (acc[curr.league.name]) {
    acc[curr.league.name] = {
      name: curr.league.name,
      team: acc[curr.league.name].team + " & " + curr.league.team
    }
  } else {
    acc[curr.league.name] = {
      name: curr.league.name,
      team: curr.league.team
    }
  }
  return acc;
}, {});
for (data in res) {
  console.log("League name: " + res[data].name + "/Team:" + res[data].team)
}
```